# XCode Warning: "Conflicting parameter types in implementation of 'viewDidAppear'"

Tags: ios, objective-c, viewdidappear

After updating XCode to version 6.3.2 warning has appeared:

> Conflicting parameter types in implementation of 'viewDidAppear: 'BOOL' vs
>   'uint8_t'

What should I do?

----edit
Here is the code:

```
- (void) viewWillAppear: (BOOL)animated
{
     //do something
}
```

Comment: Post your relevant code

Comment: Can you please implemnt the [super viewWillAppear:animated] line and then CMD+click on the viewWIllAppear part of this method and post the line that shows up after clicking?

Comment: Also you may want to clean your build CMD + Shift + K

Comment: Cleaning code doesn't work